# Openstack and devstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

Does devstack completely install openstack? I read somewhere that devStack is not and has never been intended to be a general OpenStack installer. So what does devstack actually install? Is there any other scripted method available to completely install openstack(grizzly release) or I need to follow the manual installation steps given on openstack website?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

devstack does completely install from git openstack.

for lesser values of completely anyways.  devstack is the version of openstack used in jenkins gate testing by developers committing code to the openstack project.

devstack as the name suggests is specifically for developing for openstack.  as such it's existence is ephemeral.  in short, after running stack.sh the resulting ( probably ) functioning openstack is setup... but upon reboot it will not come back up.  there are no upstart or systemd or init.d scripts for restarting services.  there is no high availability, no backups, no configuration management.  And following the latest git releases in the development branch of openstack can be a great way to discover just how unstable openstack is before a feature freeze.

there are several vagrant recipes in the world for deploying openstack, and openstack-puppet is a puppet recipe for deploying openstack.  chef also maintains an openstack recipe as well.

Grizzly is a bit old now.  Havana is the current stable release.

https://github.com/stackforge/puppet-openstack
http://docs.opscode.com/openstack.html
http://cloudarchitectmusings.com/2013/12/01/deploy-openstack-havana-on-your-laptop-using-vagrant-and-chef/

and ubuntu even maintains a system called maas and juju for deploying openstack super quickly on their OS.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mspwQfoYQks

so lots of ways to install openstack.

however most folks pushing a production cloud use some form of configuration management system.  that way they can deploy compute nodes automatically.  and recover systems quickly.

also check out openstack on openstack.

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/TripleO

Comment: Thank you Matt Joyce. That was indeed useful! Nicely explained as well!

Answer (score 5):

I think the code should be same, but at least the configuration is not same, for example, devstack will by default use nova network. In a manual installation, you can choose neutron. so:

1. if you are starting to learn openstack, devstack is a good starting point. with it, you can quickly have a development env.
2. if you are deploying openstack env, devstack is not a choice, and
   instead you need install it following the installation guide.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like another scripted option for deployment, you can try Packstack. This will work only on Fedora and RHEL.

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Packstack

https://www.rdoproject.org/install/quickstart/

In this, you can choose which services you would like to install. For example you may choose to install Neutron for networking purposes, instead of using nova.

Also, it lets you deploy multiple instances of compute nodes by just providing it's IP !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Devstack is a tool which help you build all in one for Openstack environment in quickly (Just take a coffee cup and wait until complete). Normally they were using for developer to develop new features and/ or test code quickest. For operator, we need to setup by manual step by step for each services.

- To build via devstack repo then you need pull newest source-code from http://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack. then create new local.conf in devstack folder. And run ./stack.sh.

For example local.conf: https://github.com/pshchelo/stackdev/blob/master/conf/local.conf.sample

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Devstack install all the components of Openstack. But when you use basic configuration then it will install core components of openstack which are the base of openstack cloud platform to run some basic things.

And in Advance configuration of openstack you should configure your local.conf file for what type of services and components you want to install or use in your cloud.
https://github.com/openstack/tacker/blob/master/devstack/local.conf.example